# Singularity treatment in a simple problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, singularity

With a simple search, several posts can be found on treating singularities encountered while using `NDSolve`family of numerical methods. However, most of them involve complicated functions and/or specialized problems that I don't know much about. Therefore, I haven't been able to find a simple example to understand the effectiveness of the commonly used methods (discrete variables, changing the step size, accuracy, and precision etc.).

That's why I started thinking about a reverse approach: trying to make it work for a problem for which I already have the analytical solution. If I can do this, then I should be able to gain some insight into treatment of singularities in more advanced cases.

After a few trials, I came up with a function that could make a good teaching example i.e.  $y(x)= (1-x)^{1/3}$ for which, we know the analytical derivative exists i.e. $y'(x)= (-1/3)*(1-x)^{-2/3}$.

However, solving this problem using `NDSolve` fails after the singular point:

```
NDSolve[{D[y[x], x] == -1/(3*Surd[1 - x, 3]^2), y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.9999999999999242, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

What are our options for tackling this issue? What about `"StiffnessSwitching"` methods? Is it a good idea to always try them before taking any other measures?

Also, using `WhenEvent` with `"StopIntegration"`    and then `"RestartIntegration"` sounds good, but I don't know how to pass on the value of the solution from where 'NDSolve` stops integrating to where restarting occurs or, how to specify the location for restarting automatically.